# Desearlizing an array of json objects into an object

Tags: c#, json, restsharp

I'm trying to deserialize a JSON object from the battle.net apis, I can't figure out the format of the class I'm deseralizing the json object into.

During runtime the "Races" array is always null.

I'm using the same request to collect data from the same service so its not the rest request thats the issue.

I'm using C# with the RestSharp library

Here's the json I'm deserializing:

```
{
    "races": [{
        "id": 6,
        "mask": 32,
        "side": "horde",
        "name": "Tauren"
    }, {
        "id": 5,
        "mask": 16,
        "side": "horde",
        "name": "Undead"
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "mask": 2,
        "side": "horde",
        "name": "Orc"
    }, {
        "id": 7,
        "mask": 64,
        "side": "alliance",
        "name": "Gnome"
    }, {
        "id": 9,
       "mask": 256,
        "side": "horde",
        "name": "Goblin"
    }, {
        "id": 1,
        "mask": 1,
        "side": "alliance",
        "name": "Human"
    }, {
        "id": 8,
        "mask": 128,
        "side": "horde",
        "name": "Troll"
    }, {
        "id": 24,
        "mask": 8388608,
        "side": "neutral",
        "name": "Pandaren"
    }, {
        "id": 11,
        "mask": 1024,
        "side": "alliance",
        "name": "Draenei"
    }, {
        "id": 22,
        "mask": 2097152,
        "side": "alliance",
        "name": "Worgen"
    }, {
        "id": 10,
        "mask": 512,
        "side": "horde",
        "name": "Blood Elf"
    }, {
        "id": 4,
        "mask": 8,
        "side": "alliance",
        "name": "Night Elf"
    }, {    
       "id": 3,
        "mask": 4,
        "side": "alliance",
        "name": "Dwarf"
    }, {
        "id": 25,
        "mask": 16777216,
        "side": "alliance",
        "name": "Pandaren"
    }, {
        "id": 26,
        "mask": 33554432,
        "side": "horde",
        "name": "Pandaren"
    }]
}
```

and here's the class I'm trying to deserialize into:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace RESTTests
{

    public class Race
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }


        public int Mask { get; set; }


        public string Side { get; set; }


        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class RaceData
    {

        public Race[] Races { get; set; }
    }

}
```

EDIT: More code by request

```
    public void GetRaceData()
    {
        var client = CreateClient();
        var request = CreateRequest("wow/data/character/classes");

        IRestResponse<RaceData> responseDe = client.Execute<RaceData>(request);
        RaceData race = responseDe.Data;

        //at this point "races" in the race object is null and races in the response.Data object are also null

    }

    private RestRequest CreateRequest(String segement)
    {
        var request = new RestRequest(segement, Method.GET);
        request.AddParameter("locale", _locale);
        request.AddParameter("apikey", _apiKey);
        return request;
    }

    private RestClient CreateClient()
    {
        var client = new RestClient("https://us.api.battle.net/");
        return client;
    }
```

Comment: Where's you actual deserialization code? You model classes look fine.

Comment: It may be case-sensitivity in the serializer.  try changing first character of the attributes in the input or in the classes.

Comment: @MattBurland I edited the OP with my serialization code

Answer (score 2):

You could try using [`Newtonsoft.Json`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/), for sample:

```
string json = "load your json here as a string";

Race race = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Race>(json);
```

I think the RestSharp lib already has Json.NET referenced as a dependency, so, you can use it from there.

Comment: They removed the Newtonsoft reference from RestSharp last year I think: https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/readme.txt

Comment: Nice to see, but you could add it from `NuGet` :)

Answer (score 2):

you have this class:

```
public class Race
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int mask { get; set; }
    public string side { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Race> races { get; set; }
}
```

you can always use [**json2csharp.com**](http://json2csharp.com) to get generated c# classes against json.

Comment: Tried that, the array is still null at runtime. I attached my serialization code to the OP